# Any way to mimic port password encryption to python?

Tags: java, python-3.x, encryption, sha256, jasypt

Some legacy Java uses a package called [jasypt](http://www.jasypt.org/api/jasypt/1.8/org/jasypt/util/password/StrongPasswordEncryptor.html) to encrypt password.
It uses `StrongPasswordEncryptor` to encrypt passwords.

It seems like to use below,   from their doc page
Algorithm: SHA-256.
Salt size: 16 bytes.
Iterations: 100000.

There source code [shows](https://github.com/jboss-fuse/jasypt/blob/a6cbf5419bc153698368aa796d619e67bb197ba9/jasypt/src/main/java/org/jasypt/util/password/StrongPasswordEncryptor.java)

```
 public StrongPasswordEncryptor() {
        super();
        this.digester = new StandardStringDigester();
        this.digester.setAlgorithm("SHA-256");
        this.digester.setIterations(100000);
        this.digester.setSaltSizeBytes(16);
        this.digester.initialize();
    }
```

Now that we don't use Java anymore, we'd like to continue to do the same encryption in python, but not sure how to port this portion of the code.

I do have the salt and pair of plain-text password and encrypted password to verify if python port works correctly, just don't know what lib and what functions to encrypt. Tried `hashlib.pbkdf2_hmac` without any luck.

Example plain-text password is : `Testing123`
Salt is : `0DD2E486FAE5B121491CBE78A9B67AF1`
Encrypted password is :`D1JAI76bwIkEkOIy7IZoLasAFKX0Yy7ujU/M7UBezC7NqxSD3clDyaFB1lz96K98`

Here is the snippet in Java code that actually encrypts the password:

```
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.inject.Named;
import org.jasypt.util.password.StrongPasswordEncryptor;
import com.foobar.users.PasswordEncoder;

public class PasswordEncoderImpl implements PasswordEncoder {

    private String salt;
    private StrongPasswordEncryptor encryptor;

    @Inject
    public PasswordEncoderImpl(@Named("appHash") String appHash) {
        this.salt = appHash;
        encryptor = new StrongPasswordEncryptor();
    }

    @Override
    public String encode(String password) {
        return encryptor.encryptPassword(password + salt);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean verifyPassword(String password, String encryptedPassword){
        return encryptor.checkPassword(password+salt, encryptedPassword);
    }

}
```

Comment: Try it and see if the hash matches?

Comment: @SLaks not sure how to create the hash in python. Tired hashlist to mimic it with the given info but no luck. Maybe I should download their jar and go through it, but that's just too much moving parts.

Comment: The algorithm description [is on the page you linked](http://www.jasypt.org/api/jasypt/1.8/org/jasypt/digest/StandardStringDigester.html#digest(java.lang.String)), why can't you use this?

Comment: @LukeJoshuaPark I'm not familiar with neither java nor encryption. Does that digest function layout how it encrypts the string?

Comment: @taesu the password is not encrypted, only salted hash (digest) is created. To verify the password you need to follow the link Luke provided to create a digest of provided plaintext password and stored salt. If they match, the password will match too. Correctly the salt should be unique for each password

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I got half solution for now:

Here is a simplified Java code that checks if the given password is valid:

```
private void start() throws Exception {

    String salt = "0DD2E486FAE5B121491CBE78A9B67AF1";
    String password = "Testing123";
    String previousResult = "QI2KU2VsI/aNr4U3XQ0AdaOk6Qhl4XTaN2ym5cYXxRr8tz/23EvWQHI8sNhRmoP1";

    StrongPasswordEncryptor passwordEncryptor = new StrongPasswordEncryptor();
    String encryptedPass = passwordEncryptor.encryptPassword(password + salt);


    System.out.println(checkPass(salt, password, previousResult));
    System.out.println(passwordEncryptor.checkPassword(password + salt, previousResult));
}

private boolean checkPass(String salt, String password, String previousResult) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
    byte[] bytes = previousResult.getBytes(StandardCharsets.US_ASCII);
    byte[] decode = Base64.getDecoder().decode(bytes);

    byte[] secretSalt = new byte[16];
    System.arraycopy(decode, 0, secretSalt, 0, 16);

    byte [] message = (password + salt).getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    byte[] digest = digest(message, secretSalt);

    return Arrays.equals(digest, decode);
}


private byte[] digest(byte [] message, final byte[] salt) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {

    byte[] digest;

    MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("sha-256");
    md.reset();

    md.update(salt);
    md.update(message);


    digest = md.digest();
    for (int i = 0; i < (100000 - 1); i++) {
        md.reset();
        digest = md.digest(digest);
    }

    byte[] secondArray = digest;
    final byte[] result = new byte[salt.length + secondArray.length];

    System.arraycopy(salt, 0, result, 0, salt.length);
    System.arraycopy(secondArray, 0, result, salt.length, secondArray.length);

    return result;
}
```

Comment: I am aware, but I'm more concerned about port jasypt's `StrongPasswordEncryptor` to python so we can continue verifying the hash and encrypting passwords the same way.

Comment: @taesu oh I see. Then please provide with some output example. I try to mimic it

Comment: Thank you for your time. Please see question. 
In Java code, it appends salt afterwards. 
`encryptor.encryptPassword(password + salt);`

Comment: @taesu I am not able to get the same output in Java as you do. Can you provide an example of how to get that output in Java? Where do you set the salt?

Comment: added the code in the original question. I'm literally pulling out my hair

Comment: @taesu Check out my edit. When running your example I am always getting different output. The StrongPasswordEncryptor has a random inside it

Comment: Hey, try using `encryptor.checkPassword(password+salt, encryptedPassword);`  
Everytime you encrypt, the encrypted text will be different, but when you checkPassword, it will return True

Comment: @taesu, Of course, it will! But only for that run. If you attempt to use the previous run result it will fail. Check my updated example

Comment: No, `D1JAI76bwIkEkOIy7IZoLasAFKX0Yy7ujU/M7UBezC7NqxSD3clDyaFB1lz96K98` will return True as well, thats how our Java legacy system authenticates users

Comment: @taesu Yeah you are right! Ok I try to figure this out now

Comment: Another way would be to use the jasypt jar and invoking it within python to encrypt and checkpassword, but not sure how I would go about doing it because `java -jar jasypt-1.9.2.jar` is returning `no main manifest attribute, in jasypt-1.9.2.jar`

Comment: @taesu we can translate this to Python. No worries

Comment: That would be ideal, not sure if it can happen though, maybe because I'm not a good java dev.

Comment: @taesu Hey, I got halfway thru, but need to go now. Will try to look at it tomorrow or during the weekend.